# How to properly replace the_content with the html in a php file?

Tags: plugins, php

I've built a plugin that needs to overwrite the content on a specific page. It works, but it places all head content within the body, after my own html. Is there a way to fix that?

```php
add_filter('the_content', 'overwrite_content');
 
function overwrite_content($content) {
    if(is_page('Signup')){
        require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/views/signup.php');
    } else { 
        return $content;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm bit nervous about require_once in case the the_content filter gets called twice for the same page load. Not that it should, though, but I think I've seen other questions where people were seeing that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you still see the content appearing after your HTML is because you are not returning anything in the first block of your `if()` statement. Obviously, you are outputting the HTML in the `signup.php` file, but you didn't override the original content. You can change your code to something like the following to see if you get the result you want:

```
function overwrite_content($content) {
  if (is_page('Signup')) {
    require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__).'/views/signup.php');
    $content = '';
  }
  return $content;
}
```

Comment: I'd guess you want to use ob_start() to capture the content and return that, i.e. `ob_start();` `require_once ...` `$content = ob_get_clean();`

Comment: Hi there, I tried the solutions, but they didn't work. with content I meant the content inside the head element, gets placed underneath my own content in the body tag. The head tag got escaped in my question, so I edited it, to make the question a bit more clear.